# Testing Barcode and Qrcode with Emulator of Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have developed a windows phone8 app with Bar-code and Qr-code scanning function.

Is there any possibility to test that Bar-code and Qr-code scanning with emulator, Because I

don't have a device to test.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Two Cases of applications.

1) Some Barcode/Qr-Code scanner application uses local images to scan and display output.

If your app is of this type, then you can test Your Windows Phone 8 App in the Emulator itself.

2) Some Application uses Camera to scan the Barcode/Qr-Code.

Since emulator just emulates random image (usually a simple colored block moving around corners) you can't test your application in emulator very well.